# Performing operations on Python dictionary values and add new variable to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given a dictionary, `d`, of type `{key: (v1,v2)}`, I'd like to perform a division on `v1,v2` for all keys to produce a score, `v3` so my dict is of type `{key: (v1,v2,v3)}`.

I understand I can do:

```
for key,v1,v2 in d.items():
    score = v1/v2
```

But can't work out how to then store this in the dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an easy case for a dict comprehension:

```
d2 = {key: (v1,v2,v1/v2) for key,(v1,v2) in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Example dict
d = {
    "a": (1, 2),
    "b": (3, 4)
}

# Dict comprehension
scores = { k : (v1, v2, v1 / v2) for k, (v1, v2) in d.items()}
```

Comment: This will not provide output in the form `kye:v1,v2,v3`